# Joining a column from the same dataframe in multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

This is a follow up question [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407112/merging-dataframes-with-multi-indexes-and-column-value?noredirect=1#comment120913042_68407112).

The data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B',
  16: 'C',
  17: 'C',
  18: 'C',
  19: 'C',
  20: 'C',
  21: 'C',
  22: 'C',
  23: 'C',
  24: 'D',
  25: 'D',
  26: 'D',
  27: 'D',
  28: 'D',
  29: 'D',
  30: 'D'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Apple',
  1: 'Amazon',
  2: 'Google',
  3: 'Netflix',
  4: 'Facebook',
  5: 'Uber',
  6: 'Tesla',
  7: 'total',
  8: 'Apple',
  9: 'Amazon',
  10: 'Google',
  11: 'Netflix',
  12: 'Facebook',
  13: 'Uber',
  14: 'Tesla',
  15: 'total',
  16: 'Apple',
  17: 'Amazon',
  18: 'Google',
  19: 'Netflix',
  20: 'Facebook',
  21: 'Uber',
  22: 'Tesla',
  23: 'total',
  24: 'Apple',
  25: 'Amazon',
  26: 'Google',
  27: 'Netflix',
  28: 'Uber',
  29: 'Tesla',
  30: 'total'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 88.0,
  1: 66.0,
  2: 191.0,
  3: 558.0,
  4: 12.0,
  5: 4.0,
  6: 56.0,
  7: 975.0,
  8: 90.0,
  9: 26.0,
  10: 49.0,
  11: 250.0,
  12: 7.0,
  13: 2.0,
  14: 44.0,
  15: 468.0,
  16: 36.0,
  17: 52.0,
  18: 94.0,
  19: 750.0,
  20: 10.0,
  21: 0.0,
  22: 52.0,
  23: 994.0,
  24: 16.0,
  25: 22.0,
  26: 5.0,
  27: 57.0,
  28: 3.0,
  29: 33.0,
  30: 136.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 4603.209999999999,
  1: 2485.059999999998,
  2: 4919.39999999998,
  3: 6097.77,
  4: 31.22,
  5: 155.71,
  6: 3484.99,
  7: 17237.35999999996,
  8: 561.54,
  9: 698.75,
  10: 1290.13,
  11: 4292.68000000001,
  12: 947.65,
  13: 329.0,
  14: 2889.65,
  15: 9989.4,
  16: 330.8899999999994,
  17: 2076.26,
  18: 2982.270000000004,
  19: 11978.62000000002,
  20: 683.0,
  21: 0.0,
  22: 3812.16999999999,
  23: 20963.21000000002,
  24: 234.4900000000002,
  25: 896.1,
  26: 231.0,
  27: 893.810000000001,
  28: 129.0,
  29: 1712.329999999998,
  30: 4106.729999999996},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 109.0,
  1: 48.0,
  2: 174.0,
  3: 592.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 5.0,
  6: 43.0,
  7: 984.0,
  8: 62.0,
  9: 13.0,
  10: 37.0,
  11: 196.0,
  12: 8.0,
  13: 1.0,
  14: 3.0,
  15: 30.0,
  16: 76.0,
  17: 5.0,
  18: 147.0,
  19: 88.0,
  20: 8.0,
  21: 1.0,
  22: 78.0,
  23: 1248.0,
  24: 1.0,
  25: 18.0,
  26: 23.0,
  27: 83.0,
  28: 0.0,
  29: 29.0,
  30: 154.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 3453.02,
  1: 17868.730000000003,
  2: 44707.82999999999,
  3: 61425.99,
  4: 1261.0,
  5: 1914.6000000000001,
  6: 24146.09,
  7: 154777.25999999998,
  8: 6201.489999999999,
  9: 5513.960000000001,
  10: 9645.87,
  11: 25086.785,
  12: 663.0,
  13: 448.61,
  14: 26332.7,
  15: 73892.415,
  16: 556.749999999999,
  17: 1746.859999999997,
  18: 4103.219999999994,
  19: 15571.52000000008,
  20: 86.0,
  21: 69.0,
  22: 5882.759999999995,
  23: 26476.11000000004,
  24: 53.0,
  25: 801.220000000001,
  26: 684.56,
  27: 1232.600000000002,
  28: 0.0,
  29: 15902.1,
  30: 43943.48},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-12 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 32.0,
  1: 15.0,
  2: 89.0,
  3: 239.0,
  4: 2.0,
  5: 3.0,
  6: 20.0,
  7: 400.0,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 21.0,
  17: 14.0,
  18: 58.0,
  19: 281.0,
  20: 3.0,
  21: 3.0,
  22: 33.0,
  23: 413.0,
  24: 7.0,
  25: 6.0,
  26: 4.0,
  27: 13.0,
  28: 0.0,
  29: 18.0,
  30: 48.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-12 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 2147.7000000000003,
  1: 4767.3,
  2: 2399.300000000003,
  3: 3137.440000000002,
  4: 178.0,
  5: 866.61,
  6: 10639.03,
  7: 73235.38,
  8: 0.0,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 0.0,
  11: 0.0,
  12: 0.0,
  13: 0.0,
  14: 0.0,
  15: 0.0,
  16: 220.94,
  17: 727.5199999999995,
  18: 2500.96999999999,
  19: 4414.00999999998,
  20: 15.0,
  21: 196.71,
  22: 2170.1,
  23: 9745.24999999997,
  24: 126.55,
  25: 290.2,
  26: 146.01,
  27: 233.0,
  28: 0.0,
  29: 973.18,
  30: 1658.940000000002}}).set_index(['group','category'])
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'group': {0: 'total_full',
  1: 'total_full',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'B',
  5: 'B',
  6: 'C',
  7: 'C',
  8: 'D',
  9: 'D',
  10: 'Apple_total',
  11: 'Apple_total',
  12: 'A',
  13: 'A',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B',
  16: 'C',
  17: 'C',
  18: 'D',
  19: 'D',
  20: 'Amazon_total',
  21: 'Amazon_total',
  22: 'A',
  23: 'A',
  24: 'B',
  25: 'B',
  26: 'C',
  27: 'C',
  28: 'D',
  29: 'D',
  30: 'Google_total',
  31: 'Google_total',
  32: 'A',
  33: 'A',
  34: 'B',
  35: 'B',
  36: 'C',
  37: 'C',
  38: 'D',
  39: 'D',
  40: 'Facebook_total',
  41: 'Facebook_total',
  42: 'A',
  43: 'A',
  44: 'B',
  45: 'B',
  46: 'C',
  47: 'C',
  48: 'D',
  49: 'D',
  50: 'Netflix_total',
  51: 'Netflix_total',
  52: 'A',
  53: 'A',
  54: 'B',
  55: 'B',
  56: 'C',
  57: 'C',
  58: 'D',
  59: 'D',
  60: 'Tesla_total',
  61: 'Tesla_total',
  62: 'A',
  63: 'A',
  64: 'B',
  65: 'B',
  66: 'C',
  67: 'C',
  68: 'D',
  69: 'D',
  70: 'Uber_total',
  71: 'Uber_total',
  72: 'A',
  73: 'A',
  74: 'B',
  75: 'B',
  76: 'C',
  77: 'C',
  78: 'D',
  79: 'D'},
 'category': {0: 'total_full',
  1: 'total_full',
  2: 'group_total',
  3: 'group_total',
  4: 'group_total',
  5: 'group_total',
  6: 'group_total',
  7: 'group_total',
  8: 'group_total',
  9: 'group_total',
  10: 'Apple_total',
  11: 'Apple_total',
  12: 'Apple',
  13: 'Apple',
  14: 'Apple',
  15: 'Apple',
  16: 'Apple',
  17: 'Apple',
  18: 'Apple',
  19: 'Apple',
  20: 'Amazon_total',
  21: 'Amazon_total',
  22: 'Amazon',
  23: 'Amazon',
  24: 'Amazon',
  25: 'Amazon',
  26: 'Amazon',
  27: 'Amazon',
  28: 'Amazon',
  29: 'Amazon',
  30: 'Google_total',
  31: 'Google_total',
  32: 'Google',
  33: 'Google',
  34: 'Google',
  35: 'Google',
  36: 'Google',
  37: 'Google',
  38: 'Google',
  39: 'Google',
  40: 'Facebook_total',
  41: 'Facebook_total',
  42: 'Facebook',
  43: 'Facebook',
  44: 'Facebook',
  45: 'Facebook',
  46: 'Facebook',
  47: 'Facebook',
  48: 'Facebook',
  49: 'Facebook',
  50: 'Netflix_total',
  51: 'Netflix_total',
  52: 'Netflix',
  53: 'Netflix',
  54: 'Netflix',
  55: 'Netflix',
  56: 'Netflix',
  57: 'Netflix',
  58: 'Netflix',
  59: 'Netflix',
  60: 'Tesla_total',
  61: 'Tesla_total',
  62: 'Tesla',
  63: 'Tesla',
  64: 'Tesla',
  65: 'Tesla',
  66: 'Tesla',
  67: 'Tesla',
  68: 'Tesla',
  69: 'Tesla',
  70: 'Uber_total',
  71: 'Uber_total',
  72: 'Uber',
  73: 'Uber',
  74: 'Uber',
  75: 'Uber',
  76: 'Uber',
  77: 'Uber',
  78: 'Uber',
  79: 'Uber'},
 'type': {0: 'Sales_1',
  1: 'Sales_2',
  2: 'Sales_1',
  3: 'Sales_2',
  4: 'Sales_1',
  5: 'Sales_2',
  6: 'Sales_1',
  7: 'Sales_2',
  8: 'Sales_1',
  9: 'Sales_2',
  10: 'Sales_1',
  11: 'Sales_2',
  12: 'Sales_1',
  13: 'Sales_2',
  14: 'Sales_1',
  15: 'Sales_2',
  16: 'Sales_1',
  17: 'Sales_2',
  18: 'Sales_1',
  19: 'Sales_2',
  20: 'Sales_1',
  21: 'Sales_2',
  22: 'Sales_1',
  23: 'Sales_2',
  24: 'Sales_1',
  25: 'Sales_2',
  26: 'Sales_1',
  27: 'Sales_2',
  28: 'Sales_1',
  29: 'Sales_2',
  30: 'Sales_1',
  31: 'Sales_2',
  32: 'Sales_1',
  33: 'Sales_2',
  34: 'Sales_1',
  35: 'Sales_2',
  36: 'Sales_1',
  37: 'Sales_2',
  38: 'Sales_1',
  39: 'Sales_2',
  40: 'Sales_1',
  41: 'Sales_2',
  42: 'Sales_1',
  43: 'Sales_2',
  44: 'Sales_1',
  45: 'Sales_2',
  46: 'Sales_1',
  47: 'Sales_2',
  48: 'Sales_1',
  49: 'Sales_2',
  50: 'Sales_1',
  51: 'Sales_2',
  52: 'Sales_1',
  53: 'Sales_2',
  54: 'Sales_1',
  55: 'Sales_2',
  56: 'Sales_1',
  57: 'Sales_2',
  58: 'Sales_1',
  59: 'Sales_2',
  60: 'Sales_1',
  61: 'Sales_2',
  62: 'Sales_1',
  63: 'Sales_2',
  64: 'Sales_1',
  65: 'Sales_2',
  66: 'Sales_1',
  67: 'Sales_2',
  68: 'Sales_1',
  69: 'Sales_2',
  70: 'Sales_1',
  71: 'Sales_2',
  72: 'Sales_1',
  73: 'Sales_2',
  74: 'Sales_1',
  75: 'Sales_2',
  76: 'Sales_1',
  77: 'Sales_2',
  78: 'Sales_1',
  79: 'Sales_2'},
 '2021-06-28': {0: 67.5277641202152,
  1: 82.7854700135998,
  2: 21.50082266792856,
  3: 22.03644997199996,
  4: 64.460440147,
  5: 10.1060499896,
  6: 65.1530371974946,
  7: 50.6429700519999,
  8: 56.413464107792045,
  9: 0,
  10: 17.48074540313092,
  11: 26.8376199976,
  12: 52.172,
  13: 61.16600000040001,
  14: 20.9447844,
  15: 40.69122000000001,
  16: 83.55718929717925,
  17: 14.98039999719995,
  18: 20.806771705951697,
  19: np.nan,
  20: 18.3766353690825,
  21: 12.82565001479992,
  22: 52.425508769690694,
  23: 25.661999978399994,
  24: 17.88071596,
  25: 24.384659998799997,
  26: 91.10086982794643,
  27: 12.77899003759993,
  28: 16.969540811445366,
  29: np.nan,
  30: 18.8795397517309,
  31: 26.73017999840005,
  32: 53.52039700062155,
  33: 58.81199999639999,
  34: 12.1243325,
  35: 24.0544100028,
  36: 55.94068246571674,
  37: 133.86376999920006,
  38: 7.294127785392621,
  39: np.nan,
  40: 6.07807089184563,
  41: 7.27483001599998,
  42: 2.300470581874837,
  43: 30.71300000639998,
  44: 5.810764652,
  45: 12.333119997600003,
  46: 25.475930745418292,
  47: 64.228710012,
  48: 9.490904912552498,
  49: np.nan,
  50: 8.184780211399392,
  51: 24.59321999400001,
  52: 6.807138946302334,
  53: 12.0879999972,
  54: 0.869207661,
  55: 0.324,
  56: 0.5084336040970575,
  57: 12.181219996800007,
  58: 0,
  59: np.nan,
  60: 9.293956915067886,
  61: 11.171379993599999,
  62: 6.384936971649232,
  63: 3.657999996,
  64: 0.913782413,
  65: 1.9992000012000002,
  66: 1.5322078073061867,
  67: 5.514179996399999,
  68: 0.4630297231124678,
  69: np.nan,
  70: 36.23403557795798,
  71: 53.35258999919999,
  72: 21.890370397789923,
  73: 9.937449997200002,
  74: 5.916852561,
  75: 6.319439989199998,
  76: 7.03772344983066,
  77: 37.095700012799995,
  78: 1.3890891693374032,
  79: np.nan},
 '2021-07-05': {0: 65.4690491915759,
  1: 98.5235100112003,
  2: 21.4573181155924,
  3: 241.06741999679997,
  4: 67.481716829,
  5: 11.60325000040002,
  6: 27.5807099999998,
  7: 65.8528400140003,
  8: 58.949304246983736,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 185.65887577993723,
  11: 318.9965699964001,
  12: 54.517,
  13: 66.55265999039996,
  14: 21.92632044,
  15: 43.67116000320002,
  16: 87.47349898707688,
  17: 208.7727500028001,
  18: 21.742056352860352,
  19: np.nan,
  20: 16.6038963173654,
  21: 25.28952001920013,
  22: 54.7820864335212,
  23: 36.75802000560001,
  24: 18.71872129,
  25: 30.1634600016,
  26: 95.37075040035738,
  27: 138.3680400120001,
  28: 17.73233819348684,
  29: np.nan,
  30: 14.80302342121337,
  31: 251.83851001200003,
  32: 55.926190956481534,
  33: 72.4443400032,
  34: 12.69221484,
  35: 26.032340003999998,
  36: 58.56261169338368,
  37: 153.36183000480003,
  38: 7.622005931348156,
  39: np.nan,
  40: 72.24367956241771,
  41: 14.83083001279999,
  42: 29.5726042895728,
  43: 38.723000005199985,
  44: 6.083562133,
  45: 12.845630001599998,
  46: 26.66998281055652,
  47: 63.26220000600001,
  48: 9.917530329288393,
  49: np.nan,
  50: 8.555606693927,
  51: 23.802009994800002,
  52: 7.113126469779095,
  53: 7.206999998399999,
  54: 0.910216433,
  55: 1.4089999991999997,
  56: 0.5322637911479053,
  57: 15.186009997200001,
  58: 0.0,
  59: np.nan,
  60: 9.716385738295367,
  61: 14.7327399948,
  62: 6.671946105284065,
  63: 5.691999996,
  64: 0.956574175,
  65: 1.0203399996,
  66: 1.6040220980113027,
  67: 8.020399999199999,
  68: 0.4838433599999999,
  69: np.nan,
  70: 37.88758167841983,
  71: 59.03332998119994,
  72: 22.874363860953647,
  73: 13.690399997999998,
  74: 6.194107518,
  75: 6.4613199911999954,
  76: 7.367580219466185,
  77: 38.881609991999944,
  78: 1.4515300799999995,
  79: np.nan},
 '2021-07-12': {0: 607.2971827405001,
  1: 88.9671100664001,
  2: 21.26749278974862,
  3: 17.1524199804,
  4: 64.471138092,
  5: 89.84481002279999,
  6: 26.2044999999998,
  7: 51.9698800632001,
  8: 5.354051858751745,
  9: 0.0,
  10: 177.42361595891452,
  11: 287.5395700032,
  12: 52.117,
  13: 47.388199995600004,
  14: 20.94835038,
  15: 41.4250800048,
  16: 83.57340667555117,
  17: 198.72629000280003,
  18: 20.784858903363354,
  19: np.nan,
  20: 178.323907459086,
  21: 185.83897002839998,
  22: 52.37029646474982,
  23: 27.87144997800001,
  24: 17.88339044,
  25: 23.645340010799984,
  26: 91.11855133792106,
  27: 134.3221800396,
  28: 16.95166921641509,
  29: np.nan,
  30: 128.82813286243115,
  31: 192.6867300156,
  32: 53.46403160619618,
  33: 41.412320006399995,
  34: 12.1261155,
  35: 11.840830002000002,
  36: 55.95153983444301,
  37: 139.43358000720002,
  38: 7.286445921791947,
  39: np.nan,
  40: 69.04410667683521,
  41: 93.877410018,
  42: 28.270665735943805,
  43: 27.512680004399986,
  44: 5.811656147,
  45: 5.2319800032,
  46: 25.480875296710053,
  47: 61.132750010400024,
  48: 9.480909497181356,
  49: np.nan,
  50: 8.178601399067174,
  51: 17.6743199976,
  52: 6.7999699585309585,
  53: 6.131999998799999,
  54: 0.870099156,
  55: 0.6185600004,
  56: 0.5085322845362154,
  57: 10.923759998400003,
  58: 0.0,
  59: np.nan,
  60: 9.287042311133577,
  61: 19.966500000000007,
  62: 6.378212628950804,
  63: 6.524999997600001,
  64: 0.913782413,
  65: 1.9303400016,
  66: 1.5325051891827732,
  67: 11.511160000800006,
  68: 0.4625420799999998,
  69: np.nan,
  70: 36.21177607303267,
  71: 51.3836100036,
  72: 21.86731639537707,
  73: 10.310769999600003,
  74: 5.917744056,
  75: 5.152679999999999,
  76: 7.039089381655591,
  77: 35.920160003999996,
  78: 1.3876262399999995,
  79: np.nan}}).set_index(['group','category','type'])
```

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)
df = (df1.merge(df2.rename(columns=f).unstack(), left_index=True, right_index=True)
        .sort_index(axis=1))
```

I am trying to add a column `last_week_sales` to each multiindex column.
[image]

So the `total_sales` from the previous week becomes `last_week_sales` in the following week in every multiindex column except for the first week as there are no data of the previous week.

What I've tried:

```
pd.merge(df.shift(-4, axis = 1).xs('total_sales', level=1,drop_level=False))
```

I am not sure how I can select only the second index, few answers suggested using `.xs()` but I am not sure how I would merge it on the `date` column, I tried shifting everything by `-4` as then I get the desired week shift, but maybe there are better ways of achieving this.

Right now `df.columns` return

```
MultiIndex([('2021-06-28',      'Sales_1'),
            ('2021-06-28',      'Sales_2'),
            ('2021-06-28', 'total_orders'),
            ('2021-06-28',  'total_sales'),
            ('2021-07-05',      'Sales_1'),
            ('2021-07-05',      'Sales_2'),
            ('2021-07-05', 'total_orders'),
            ('2021-07-05',  'total_sales'),
            ('2021-07-12',      'Sales_1'),
            ('2021-07-12',      'Sales_2'),
            ('2021-07-12', 'total_orders'),
            ('2021-07-12',  'total_sales')])
```

And I would like to have:

```
MultiIndex([('2021-06-28',      'Sales_1'),
            ('2021-06-28',      'Sales_2'),
            ('2021-06-28', 'total_orders'),
            ('2021-06-28',  'total_sales'),
            ('2021-06-28',  'last_week_sales')
            ('2021-07-05',      'Sales_1'),
            ('2021-07-05',      'Sales_2'),
            ('2021-07-05', 'total_orders'),
            ('2021-07-05',  'total_sales'),
            ('2021-07-05',  'last_week_sales')
            ('2021-07-12',      'Sales_1'),
            ('2021-07-12',      'Sales_2'),
            ('2021-07-12', 'total_orders'),
            ('2021-07-12',  'total_sales'),
            ('2021-07-12',  'last_week_sales')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do in steps

- Select the cross section of dataframe using `loc`
- Shift the cross section along the columns axis
- Rename `total_sales` to `last_week_sales` and combine the cross section with `df`

```
s = df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'total_sales')].shift(axis=1)
s = s.rename({'total_sales': 'last_week_sales'}, axis=1, level=1)

df.combine_first(s)
```

Comment: Thank you, why do we need to use `slice(None)`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis `slice(None)` is needed because we have to select all the `level=0` columns corresponding to `total_sales` column.

Comment: And if I wanted to calculate the difference between `total_sales` and `last_week_sales` for each `date` column, I tried `df_out.loc[:,(slice(None),'total_sales')] - df_out.loc[:,(slice(None),'last_week_sales')]` but I get only `nan` values.

Comment: The column names in the multiindex needs to be matched if you want to subtract those. `xs` would be useful in that case check `df_out.xs('total_sales', axis=1, level=1) - df_out.xs('last_week_sales', axis=1, level=1)`